# Ошибка запуска скрипта Active Perl

Tags: active-perl, perl

Плиз помогите чайнику. Всунула скрипт в cmd, выдал что-то вроде..ниже..  ЭТОТ СКРИН НЕ МОЙ, НО ПРОСТ ПОХОЖ НА МОЙ, ЧАЙНИКА, ВЗГЛЯД, Я ПИХАЛА В ____.txt____!!

[image: командная строка]

Как именно теперь нужно исправить пеер порт?
З.Ы. (что эта за штука, и с чем ее едят не знаю, но весь трабл по ходу в этом...)

Comment: Какие ещё "пеер порт" ? Перл ясно сказал, что тут ошибки в каждой строке.
Выложите чтоли сам код скрипта.

Answer (score 4):

По всей видимости вы скопировали код из Word'а или какого-то другого редактора, в котором поддерживается дополнительное форматирование текста.
Скопируйте текст например в Notepad, чтобы там не было rtf1 или т. п. вещей, сохраните файл и попробуйте запустить еще раз.

Comment: Точно, это RTF прёт.

Comment: Поправка. Не "скопировали РТФ", а пытаемся открыть перлом РТФ файл. Он там начинается {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\ ....